# Woocommerce minimum number of products per category

Tags: woocommerce

I need a snippet that having several products of a category the minimum order of products per category is 3 units. I.e. you can order 3 units of the same product or 1 unit of 3 different products but of the same category. In case it is not fulfilled it must show an error message. Thank you.

I have tried the following snippet with no result.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_check_cart_items', 'wc_min_item_required_qty' );
function wc_min_item_required_qty() {
    $categories    = array('Vinos'); // The targeted product category
    $min_item_qty  = 2; // Minimum Qty required (for each item)
    $display_error = false; // Initializing

    // Loop through cart items
    foreach(WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        $item_quantity = $cart_item['quantity']; // Cart item quantity
        $product_id    = $cart_item['product_id']; // The product ID

        // For cart items remaining to "Noten" producct category
        if( has_term( $categories, 'product_cat', $product_id ) && $item_quantity < $min_item_qty ) {
            wc_clear_notices(); // Clear all other notices

            // Add an error notice (and avoid checkout).
            wc_add_notice( sprintf( 'Bitte beachte die Mindestbestellmenge. Du brauchst mindestens %s Notenexemplare pro Arrangement. Aktuell hast du %s Stück in deinem Warenkorb.', $min_item_qty , $item_quantity ), 'error' );
            break; // Stop the loop
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this hook wont trigger on single product page if thats where you have issues. use woocommerce_add_to_cart - https://wp-kama.com/plugin/woocommerce/hook/woocommerce_add_to_cart

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to set a minimum order of 3 units per category, but your code is currently set to a minimum of 2 units (`$min_item_qty = 2;`). You should change this to 3.

Also, you're checking if the quantity of each product is less than the minimum. This won't work if the customer has 1 unit of 3 different products. Instead, you should check if the total quantity of products in the category is less than the minimum.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_check_cart_items', 'wc_min_item_required_qty' );
function wc_min_item_required_qty() {
$categories = array('simple'); // The targeted product category
$min_item_qty = 3; // Minimum Qty required (per category)
$category_qty = 0; // Initializing

// Loop through cart items
foreach(WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
$item_quantity = $cart_item['quantity']; // Cart item quantity
$product_id = $cart_item['product_id']; // The product ID

// If the product is in the targeted category, add its quantity to the category total
if( has_term( $categories, 'product_cat', $product_id ) ) {
$category_qty += $item_quantity;
}
}

// If the total quantity of products in the category is less than the minimum, display an error
if( $category_qty < $min_item_qty ) {
wc_clear_notices(); // Clear all other notices

// Add an error notice (and avoid checkout).
wc_add_notice( sprintf( 'A minimum of %s items per category is required. You currently have %s item(s) in your cart.', $min_item_qty , $category_qty ), 'error' );
}
}
```

Here is the output: https://dsh.re/eb809

**Note:** Make sure to use either classic block or shortcode on the cart and checkout page.

Check if the product is a pack of bottles and skip the minimum quantity check:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_check_cart_items', 'wc_min_item_required_qty' );
function wc_min_item_required_qty() {
$categories = array('simple'); // The targeted product category
$min_item_qty = 3; // Minimum Qty required (per category)
$category_qty = 0; // Initializing
$has_pack = false; // Initializing

// Loop through cart items
foreach(WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
$item_quantity = $cart_item['quantity']; // Cart item quantity
$product_id = $cart_item['product_id']; // The product ID

// Check if the product is a pack of bottles
if( has_term( 'pack', 'product_cat', $product_id ) ) {
$has_pack = true;
}

// If the product is in the targeted category, add its quantity to the category total
if( has_term( $categories, 'product_cat', $product_id ) ) {
$category_qty += $item_quantity;
}
}

// If the total quantity of products in the category is less than the minimum and there's no pack in the cart, display an error
if( $category_qty < $min_item_qty && !$has_pack ) {
wc_clear_notices(); // Clear all other notices

// Add an error notice (and avoid checkout).
wc_add_notice( sprintf( 'A minimum of %s items per category is required. You currently have %s item(s) in your cart.', $min_item_qty , $category_qty ), 'error' );
}
}
```

Comment: On more question, if ití possible. I sell single bottles of wine and packs of bottles of wine. Single bottles are sold with a minimum of 3 units but in the case that an order has a pack of bottles of wine you can also order bottles of wine without having to comply with the rule of 3 units as a minimum. How can I include this condition in the snippet?

Comment: You need to add an extra condition in the loop that checks if the product is a pack of bottles. I have updated my answer above. (please accept the answer if it helps)

Comment: Thanks Shameen, I'm sorry, but it doesn't do the function I need. in the case that the cart has a bottle of wine and a wine pack, it doesn't allow the purchase and should let you checkout.  The minimum sales condition of 3 bottles of wine is valid only if there is no product from the pack category in the cart.